# how to create a scheduled task that runs when any user logins to the system

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, settings, startup-folder

I want to launch an exe file of my product (C:\ClassConnect\class_server.cmd) on user login.
 I tried 2 solutions ( but nothing seems to work)
Solution 1 : ( Added Startup Shortcut )

It asks the user for UAC dialog, which obviously my users will not accept as its a spy app.
Solution 2 : ( Added batch to windows scheduler so that it runs for any user)

It runs fine with the administrator account but fails for other users.
Moreover I am not able to view scheduled tasks on other users

Please help. ( I want the batch to run on startup for all users on my machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling my head for so many days, I finally found the answer for running the program as admin

I wrote the following batch file to run one of my system program in admin mode without UAC Popup( it auto Enters the admin password )

I wrote a batch file  run.bat with following content => it then executes a vb script which waits for 5 second and keys in the password.

================run.bat Start========================

```
set USER_NAME="administrator"
set PASSWORD="test"
set PROGRAM_NAME="C:\\ClassConnect\\class_student.bat"
set "cm=cscript /B /nologo runas4.vbs %PASSWORD%"
%cm%
runas /profile /env /user:%USER_NAME% "%PROGRAM_NAME%"
```

================run.bat End========================

================runas4.vbs Start========================

```
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
password=objArgs(0)
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 5000
bWindowFound = WshShell.AppActivate("ClassConnect_Teacher")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys password
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
set WshShell = nothing
```

================runas4.vbs End========================

The above script waits for 5 second and then enters the password for runas command thus I am able to run the script in admin mode.

**If you are not sure about your access rights, download the isadmin.exe from internet.**

if you do not have admin access on the system , activate the default disabled Administrator account. You can activate the account by using

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

For resetting the default administrator password use:
    net user administrator *

Comment: @yanick can you review?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to put your class_server.cmd file in the alluser start-up folder:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Or call your .cmd file via shortcut and runas in the start-up folder to solve the UAC problem. Follow this documentation: http://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/

Comment: but in that case it asks for UAC dialog and moreover I want to run the batch as an administrator

Comment: Visited your reference webpage I tried creating a windows task -> it works fine with local administrator account. It does not launch the batch on other accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! The app that I am trying to run is a spy app, When I create a shortcut to run as administrator -> Everytime I restart my machine it asks for password which a person sitting on the computer will not enter. Kindly provide a solution wherein we don't need to enter password multiple times ( first time is OKAY)

Comment: well I tried the solution and I just have to enter the PW once. Maybe there is something wrong with your runas command. Could you post it?

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:TWINGS-COMP7\technowings-pc /savecred "C:\Program Files (x86)\ClassConnect\class_student.bat"

Comment: Is there a software installed which resets your HDD after a reboot? Something like HDGuard?

Comment: No ... I tried it on 5 machines and not working any of them .. Machines are Windows 8,Windows 7 64 bit and 32 bit

Comment: See when I run the                                                   [runas /savecred /user:TWINGS-COMP7\technowings-pc BATCH_FILE_PATH]           on standard user account -> It asks for the password only for the first time but in admin account it keeps asking password after restart of machine

Comment: I tried the following script for run as admin  [runas /profile /env /user:%user_name1% "%~1"